# Passing 2D Dynamic Array in a Function with parameter from array.h in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I've separated my code into 3 files: main.cpp, array.h, array.cpp

My code asks the user to input size of a square 2D matrix and I implement some functions (transpose, addition of 2 2D Arrays, etc)

my array.cpp's constructor initializes a dynamic array of size s and puts all entries to 0s.

```
Array::Array(int s)
{
    // The constructor creates a dynamic array v[s][s], and set size to s.
    // initialize all entries v[i][j] to 0.
    int **v = new int*[s];
    for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
        v[i] = new int[s];

    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            v[i][j] = 0;
}

Array::~Array()
{
    // The destructor deletes v.
    int arraysize = sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i)
    {
        delete [] v[i];
    }
    delete [] v;

}
```

This is part of my main.cpp that i'm having trouble with. 
I have a function asking the user to input entries for 2d array on the top of my main function, but I've been getting error "type 'Array' does not provide a subscript operator"

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "array.h"

    using namespace std;

    // input array

    void input(Array &C)
    {
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; C[i][0] == 0; i++)
            for(j = 0; C[0][j] == 0; j++)
            {
                cin >> C[i][j];
            }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        //input size
        int size;
        cout << "Please input array size:" << endl;
        cin >> size;

        //input A, B
        Array A(size), B(size);
        cout << "Please input " << size << "x" << size << "integer array A:" << endl;
        input(A);
        cout << "Please input " << size << "x" << size << "integer array B:" << endl;
        input(B);

........
```

I have to use the parameter (Array &C) for the input function, but I'm not sure how to change the body of the input funtion

Comment: Well, type `Array` doesn't have `operator[]`. Also, the destructor is very wrong.

Comment: You'll need to overload the subscript operator and have it return some object that's type has also overloaded it. On a side note your `input` function has undefined behaviour because it will start trying to access out of bounds.

Comment: `sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0])` does not do what you expect it to do. This would work for a statically allocated array, not for a dynamically allocated array. `sizeof` is translated during compilation-time by applying it on the type of of the operand. In your case, the operand is `v` and its type is `int**`. Therefore, `sizeof(v)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int**)`, and `sizeof(v[0])` is equivalent to `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: Please add the declaration of your class to the question. What are its members?

Comment: Why are you creating your own dynamic array?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the expression `sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0])` does not do what you expect it to do.

This would work for a statically-allocated array, not for a dynamically-allocated array.

A `sizeof` expression is translated during compilation-time, by applying it on the type of of the operand.

In your case, the operand is `v` and its type is `int**`.

Therefore, `sizeof(v)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int**)`, and `sizeof(v[0])` is equivalent to `sizeof(int*)`.

You expect the expression `sizeof(v)` to give you the size of the dynamically-allocated array pointed by `v`, but the compiler cannot guess (during compilation-time) what this size is going to be during runtime.

With regards to the actual question at hand (and as already mentioned in a comment to it), you'll need to implement the following functions in your `Array` class:

1. Reader - `int* Array::operator[](int index) const {return v[index];}`
2. Writer - `int*& Array::operator[](int index) {return v[index];}`

BTW, declaring in the constructor a local variable named `v`, will result in the initialization of that local variable instead of in the initialization of the member variable of the same name.

Comment: @Bob__: You're right, it should be `int*` (and `int*&`).

Comment: Quoting a comment in OP's code: *"// The constructor creates a dynamic array v[s][s], and set size to s."*. I *assume* (OP doesn't show) that `v` is already a member of the class and so `s` should be ;).

Comment: @Bob__: Well, if you do `int **v = ...` in the constructor, then even if you have a member variable named `v`, it will not be initialized here (the local variable will).

Comment: @Bob__: Just did :)